# Angular стилизация фрагмента

Tags: css, angular2, angular4

Нужно стилизовать фрагмент  в Angular,  подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

```
 <div class="title-block">Interval #{{i + 1}} - {{ item.type == 'lorem' ? 'Lorem type' : 'Style type' }}</div>
```

Нужно добавить другие стили вот этому кусочку `'Style type'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно этот кусочек обернуть в тег  и дать ему класс:

```
<div class="title-block">Interval #{{i + 1}} - <span class="someClass">{{ item.type == 'lorem' ? 'Lorem type' : 'Style type' }}</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно обернуть и задавать класс по тому же условию:

```
<div class="title-block">
    Interval #{{i + 1}} - 
    <span [ngClass]="{'someclass': item.type != 'lorem' }">
        {{ item.type == 'lorem' ? 'Lorem type' : 'Style type' }}
    </span>
</div>
```